# Repeticion de numero random

Tags: javascript, condiciones

Cómo podría hacer una condición que te muestre cierto mensaje después de que cierto numero random se repita 7 veces? Por ejemplo:

```
  var gana = localStorage.getItem('j1');
  if (gana == c) {
      alert("Gana jug1");
  }
```

tengo ese código que en la variable gana se elige un numero ya ingresado y guardado en localstorage como j1 y si el numero random es el mismo que el ingresado te muestra la alerta pero no sé como hacerle para que me muestre esa alerta cuando tal numero se repitió 7 veces y no solo una que es como tengo el código.

```
 $('#boton-guardar').click(function(){       
   var num= $('#num1').val();

    if (num > 1 && num <13) {
    localStorage.setItem('j1', num);
   num= $('#num1').val('');
   var numero1 = localStorage.getItem('j1');
    $("#numj1").html(numero1);
} 
else{
    alert("Ingresa un numero valido")
    }     
});
```

El valor ingresado lo guardo como j1 en localStorage.

Comment: Puedes publicar el código de cuando se guarda el número en `localStorage`?

Comment: Tienes que almacenar también las veces que se ha mostrado ese número, cada ves que se muestre aumentas ese numero en 1 y preguntas por el mismo si ha llegado a 7.

Answer (score 1):

crear un arreglo con posiciones ejemplo
si el numero maximo es 7

```
var m_numero =7;
var array=[];
var numero_ganador = 9;
if(array[numero] == undefined){
   array[numero]=1;
}else{
  array[numero]= eval(array[numero])+1;
}

if (array[numero_ganador] != undefined && array[numero_ganador] == m_numero){
  alert("el numero se repitio: "+m_numero);
}
```

Comment: Pero ahí en el codigo donde haces la comparación de el numero ingresado y el numero random? por ejemplo en el mio la var C es el numero random y gana es el numero ingresado (que es el que se debe repetir 7 veces para mostrar la alerta)

Comment: ya corregi para que se entienda mejor!

Comment: y ahí la comparacion entre el numero random y el ganador cual seria?

Comment: por ejemplo en mi codigo la comparacion es 
if(c==gana).......